# Where to specify credential details in Azure Information Protection AzureIP_test sample

Tags: data-protection, azure-information-protection, microsoft-information-protection

I'm trying to get the [AzureIP_test sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Azure-Information-Protection-Samples/tree/master/AzureIP_Test) to work, but am having trouble figuring out where to specify certain credential details.

When I run my version of the sample against a test document, I get the following error:

`An unexpected error occurred : Microsoft.InformationProtectionAndControl.InformationProtectionException: The parameter is incorrect. HRESULT: 0x80070057`

I suspect I'm missing credential details, but I don't know where to specify the the details in the application.

Specifically, I *think* I need the following:

`SymmetricKeyCredential symmetricKeyCred = new SymmetricKeyCredential();
symmetricKeyCred.AppPrincipalId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppPrincipalId"];
symmetricKeyCred.Base64Key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Base64Key"];
symmetricKeyCred.BposTenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BposTenantId"];`

Does anyone know the best place to specify these details?  Are there other useful details I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to provide your AAD Application registration information and how you logon with in the App.Config file that is associated with the sample you are using on GitHub

-------BEGINNING OF THE APP CONFIG FILE------

/.auth/login/done" />

-------END OF APP CONFIG file ---------------------